# Synonimize [titles] to [title]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I came across the [titles](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) tag when searching for the [title](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title) tag.

- Questions tagged [titles](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles): 13
- Questions tagged [title](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title): 208

It seems like an uncontroversial synonym to make (from [titles](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) to [title](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title)).

(If it were 2 or 3 questions I would just replace the tag manually, but 13 seems like too many questions to bump to the front page with edits.)

Answer (score 5):

I agree that this tag synonym should be created.    We'll do it in a few days unless other people disagree.

Edit:  The tag merge and synonym creation has been completed.

Comment: No disagreement here